# find mean of a column in a matrix with multiple conditions

Tags: r, matrix, mean

I have a 4 column matrix called storm reports, the first column is a ranking index on how severe the storm is and the 3rd column is number of hail reports in a storm. I am being asked to find the mean number of hail reports (column 3), with a ranking index greater than 0.25 (column 1).I was told I could use a which statement. Thank you so much. Here's a sample matrix:

sample matrix:

```
strm_reports <- matrix(c(0.276, 20, 108, 21,
0.494, 10, 247, 31,
0.008, 14, 38,  49,
0.076, 1,  232, 30,
0.085, 7,  97,  5), ncol = 4)
```

This is what I have tried:

```
mean_hail<-mean(sum(ifelse(strm_reports[,3] & strm_reports[,1]>0.25,1,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

you're right, `which` is *a* way to go

```
mean(strm_reports[which(strm_reports[,1] > .25), 3])
```

If you're having trouble understanding, you should step through the above code:

```
which(strm_reports[,1] > .25) #returns row indices for TRUE statements

#returns only the values from the column we're interested in
strm_reports[which(strm_reports > .25), 3]
```

In fact, we don't have to use `which`

```
strm_reports[,1] > .25 #returns a vector of TRUE and FALSE
strm_reports[strm_reports[,1] > .25, 3] 
mean(strm_reports[strm_reports[,1] > .25, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `dplyr` package

```
filter(strm_reports,strm_reports[,1]>0.25) %>% mutate(Mean_C3 = mean(C3))
```

**Data**

```
strm_reports <- matrix(c(0.276, 20, 108, 21,
0.494, 10, 247, 31,
0.008, 14, 38,  49,
0.076, 1,  232, 30,
0.085, 7,  97,  5), ncol = 4,byrow = TRUE)
strm_reports <- as.data.frame.matrix(strm_reports)
colnames(strm_reports) <- paste("C",1:4,sep = "")
```